# Updating data in a column based on a join with foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some incorrect data, which I want to correct. For ex - In the 'address_detail' table, the address field is wrongly prefixed with 'null' instead of the city name.

```
id | city_id | address
-----------------------------
7  |    1    | null/Street39
8  |    2    | null/Street40
9  |    3    | null/Street41
10 |    4    | null/Street42

city table 

id  | name
--------------- 
1   | Mexico    
2   | New York  
3   | Washington    
4   | Los Angeles
```

After correction, I want the data to be like :

address_detail table

```
id  | city_id   | address
-------------------------------
7   | 1         | Mexico/Street39
8   | 2         | New York/Street40
9   | 3         | Washington/Street41
10  | 4         | Los Angeles/Street42
```

I tried the following script but gives me error.

```
UPDATE
    address_detail ad
SET
    ad.address = (CONCAT( SELECT name FROM city c WHERE c.id = ad.city_id, SUBSTRING( ad.address, 5 )))
WHERE
    ad.address LIKE 'null/%'
```

Comment: Please provide the error you got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    address_detail ad
SET
    ad.address = REPLACE(ad.address, 'null', ( SELECT name FROM city c WHERE c.id = ad.city_id))
WHERE
    ad.address LIKE 'null/%'
```